# Second hide and show div with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, yesterday I got advice with my html code which shows a div with text when I press on a link.

This is what I have https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/3/

Got any idea after I get a div to show, an example if I click "felge"( in english wheels) I get BBS ENKEI and KONIG, I want to make those three also clickable to get a third div next to them, so basicly when i pick wheel from first div, bbs, enkei and konig appear and then those are clickable too, and then I can pick one of those from the second div to show a third one.

I tried this :

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link1')" id="link1">Felge</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link2')" id="link2">Gume</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link3')" id="link3">Branici</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link4')" id="link4">Farovi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked div" id="content1">
            <ul>
             --->   <li><a href="javascript:show('felga1')" id="felgaLink1">BBS</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:show('felga2')" id="felgaLink2">ENKEI</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:show('felga3')" id="felgaLink3">KONIG</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content2">
                <p>Michelin</p>
                <p>Hankook</p>
                <p>Sava</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content3">
            <p>AMG</p>
            <p>Brabus</p>
            <p>Original</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content4">
            <p>Angel Eyes</p>
            <p>Devil Eyes</p>
            <p>Original</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

where I added a href in the second div, its marked with an arrow in the code above and did the same script with diferent names as for the first hide/show div but it doesnt work as it should. How should/could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you adding subcontent divs

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="div" id="subcontent1">
        <p>BBS</p>
        <p>ENKEI</p>
        <p>KONIG</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="subcontent2">
        <p>Michelin</p>
        <p>Hankook</p>
        <p>Sava</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="subcontent3">
        <p>AMG</p>
        <p>Brabus</p>
        <p>Original</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="subcontent4">
        <p>Angel Eyes</p>
        <p>Devil Eyes</p>
        <p>Original</p>
    </div>
</div>`
```

and adding another javascript function

```
function showsub(id) {
    var number = id.replace('sublink', '');
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=subcontent");
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.querySelector('#subcontent' + number).style.display = 'block';
}



function show(id) {
    var number = id.replace('link', '');
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=content");
    var subblocks = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=subcontent");
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < subblocks.length; j++) {
        subblocks[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.querySelector('#content' + number).style.display = 'block';
}
```

and position it according to where you need

Comment: Cant get this one to work, if I do this way, then those subcontents arent clickable, because they use <p> .      If I use your body then the links dont work, doesnt even show second div with BBS,Enkei etc.

Comment: For that you need to wrap in href  "<a href="javascript:show('sublink1')" id="sublink1">Felge</a>"  something like this

Comment: I added sublinks to second divs, now it has a link but when I click on one of them they all disapear, code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8nbzbabb/

Comment: i think you repeating same javascript function. please use https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/3/ to work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/5/ This is my entire code, I have it like this, the second div disapears when clicked on. In which part is the problem here?